# react I want to output the array in multiple tags rather than one tag

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

We have now put `json array` data in the functionSupplement variable.
If you print this `<p>functionSupplement </p>`, you will get something like this.

How can I write code to get it to work the way I want it to?

```
<p>
"Hi" 
"Hi"
</p>
```

I want to make it like this.

```
<p>
"Hi"
</p>
<p>
"Hi"
</p>
```

This is my code.

```
let functionSupplement = ProductDetail && ProductDetail.chart?.functionalsInfo?.[0].materialsInfo.map(array => array.ingredientsInfo?.[0].mFunctionalDisplayText);

console.log(functionSupplement) // (2) ["Hi","Hi]
   
return (
          <div>
          <p>{functionSupplement}</p>  //<p>"Hi" "Hi"</p>
          </div>
)
```

Comment: As other users said, just use map, but remember to use the `key` prop as the example of @Joshua Craven

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the .map property like so :

```
let functionSupplement = ProductDetail && ProductDetail.chart?.functionalsInfo?.[0].materialsInfo.map(array => array.ingredientsInfo?.[0].mFunctionalDisplayText);

console.log(functionSupplement) // (2) ["Hi","Hi]

    return (
        <div>
          {functionSupplement.map(item=> <p>{item}</p>)}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use `map` on the list.

For more info, see: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Here's a working example based on your code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <body>

    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/babel">
    'use strict';

    let functionSupplement = ["hi", "hello"];
    
    const paragraphs = functionSupplement.map((item) =>
      <p key={item}>{item}</p>
    );

    ReactDOM.render(paragraphs,document.getElementById('root'));
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

### String with newlines `/n`

I would assume you just want your content to **appear** on separate lines.

You can use the `<pre>` tag to render content as it is.

```js
const content = `this is line 1
this is line 2
this is line 3`


class Snippet extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (<div><pre>{ content }</pre></div>)
   }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <Snippet />,
  document.body
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

### Arrays

If you are rendering an array you can also use `.map` to loop through the array.

```js
const content = ['this is line 1','this is line 2','this is line 3']


class Snippet extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (<div>{ content.map( (x,i) => <p key={i}>{x}</p>) }</div>)
   }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <Snippet />,
  document.body
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

simply be .map() its possible to iterate, and code reusability is achieved,

```
{functionSupplement.map(e=><p>{e}</p>)}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
render() {
    return <div>
    {
        functionSupplement.map((mgs) =><p>{mgs}</p>)
    }
    </div>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the `<div>` around like in the other answers, [`<React.Fragment />`](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) (or `<>` and `</>`) comes to your rescue (which renders as [`DocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment)):

```js
render() {
    return <React.Fragment>
        {functionSupplement.map((mgs) =><p>{mgs}</p>)}
    </React.Fragment>;
}
```